# Using magrittr and lapply to divide a column in each df in a list by a list of values

Tags: r, lapply, magrittr

I have a list of dataframes containing different time series of different lengths. I want to summarize the count of a variable and then normalize it by the number of years of data that is contained in that particular dataset.

so with a sample dataframe:

```
data_list <- list(data.frame(temp_bin = rep(1:4, 2:5), value = runif(14)),
  data.frame(temp_bin = rep(1:4, 3:6), value = runif(18)), 
  data.frame(temp_bin = rep(1:4, 4:7), value = runif(22)))
# this might be ~10 different data sets with ~ 100k observations each

count <- lapply(data_list, function(x) {nrow(x)/5} )
#  for real data this would be divided by 8760 for the # of hours in a year.
```

Here is approximately what I want to do, but the n()/count doesn't work because count is a list.

```
data_bin <- data_list %>%
  lapply(., group_by, temp_bin) %>%
  lapply(., summarise, n = n()/count)
```

I tried doing an lapply or mapply within the definition of n, but that didn't seem to work. also tried doing it in two steps - create get a raw n value and then divide in the next step with mapply, but that didn't work either.

Comment: you could melt your list into one long format data.frame, perhaps more suitable for dplyr `melt(data_list, id=1:2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the `count` step in your `data_bin` step I think it accomplishes what you want, though I am a little hazy on exactly what you mean but I think this works: (Note that you can remove the `.` assignment from the first argument of `lapply`, that's the default behavior of `%>%`)

```
data_bin <- data_list %>%
 lapply(group_by, temp_bin) %>%
 # We need x so I put summarize in a manual function
 lapply(function(x){summarize(x,n = 5*n()/nrow(x))}) # move the 5 to numerator

data_bin[[1]]
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  temp_bin         n
1        1 0.7142857
2        2 1.0714286
3        3 1.4285714
4        4 1.7857143
```

Is this what you wanted? You can double check the summarize is part is doing what you want by just returning the `nrow(x)` result.

```
data_bin <- data_list %>%
 lapply(group_by, temp_bin) %>%
 lapply(function(x){summarize(x,n = nrow(x))}) 

data_bin[[1]]
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

temp_bin  n
1        1 14
2        2 14
3        3 14
4        4 14
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid using `lapply` on every row of a `dplyr` statement. You could wrap individual `data.frame` transformation in a function and then `lapply` that function to `data_list`

```
library(dplyr)

ret_db <- function(df) {
  db <- df %>%
    group_by(.,temp_bin) %>%
    summarise(.,n=n()/(nrow(df)/5))
  return(db)
}

data_bin <- lapply(data_list,ret_db)
```

Comment: That would definitely work. Why would you recommend creating a function for that rather than using lapply? Processing speed?

Comment: Not for processing speed, but for consistency, because I think dplyr code is easier to read this way. Moreover, without a function, you would have to add lapply to every line of your transformation ; with a function, you only write it once.